# Magento 2.2.6 redirect 302 loop with iwd onepage checkout extension

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, third-party-module

I have problem with iwd onepage checkout extension in my store. Now Magento 2.2.6 but earlier versions too.

If IWD Onepage checkout is enabled by cli, https://domain.com/checkout/cart is working. 
But when user click "proceed to checkout" redirect loop is starting.

This is 302 redirect loop between https://domain.com/checkout and https://domain.com/onepage address.

I was check many other posts similar like that:
 - redirect loop in adminpanel
 - or between http and https for the same address
 - cookie settings and clear browser cache
 - clear/disable nginx by engintron for cpanel
but it's not solution for me.

Option like web/secure/use_in_frontend and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml is enabled and store, adminpanel, checkout (without iwd opc) is working good. However clear instalation second shop in https://domain.com/testshop with this extension is working.

IWD Opc extension has some custom empty cart page. But in my store it is no display (extension is enabled but only default empty page is working). But with empty cart, there is no redirect loop (and no problem:))
I was try change theme to clear luma - with the same effect.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem with redirect loop?

Answer (score 1):

I was "solve" my problem by using other free one page checkout extension.
https://marketplace.magento.com/espl-onepagecheckout.html